# t-sql 2008 r2 where statement with several not items

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In t-sql 2008 r2, I am trying to determine how to setup the sql to accomplish the following
goal:

```
SELECT table1.customer_id, 
       type, 
       start_date, 
       end_date, 
       program_id 
FROM   table1 
       JOIN table2 
         ON table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
```

1. where type not= ('aa','cc') and type not = 'g2' where code = 3
   In table1 there are lots of records for each customer_id and there can be
   lots of various values for type. I only want the customer_ids that do not contain
   the values listed above.
   and
2. table2 has only one customer_id. Customer_id is the key of table2.
   I want customers that do not have a value in one of the 3 columns:
   start_date, end_date, and program_id.

Both parts 1 and 2 listed above need to be true for the customer_id to be selected.
Thus can you tell me how to setup that sql?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results instead of word problems.

Comment: Please tell me you don't have 2 values stored in one cell of Type(ex.'aa', 'cc' in the same cell?). This will break normalization if you do.

Comment: @Jason i think what he wants to do is `(type not in ('aa','cc') or (type <> 'g2' and code = 3))`

Comment: Oh you may be right @rs. its hard to tell with the way he worded it

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you exactly because I cannot see your database structure but I believe it would be something like this:

```
   SELECT table1.customer_id,type,start_date,end_date,Program_id
    FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
    WHERE (table1.type NOT IN('aa', 'cc', 'g2') AND table1.code = 3)
    AND (table2.start_data IS NULL OR table2.end_date IS NULL OR table2.program_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: your query is not considering type <>'g2'

Answer (score 0):

Give the check to Jason(+1) but I would pull conditions into the join
Sometimes that helps the query optimizer

```
SELECT table1.customer_id,type,start_date,end_date,Program_id
  FROM table1 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
   AND table1.type NOT IN ('aa', 'cc') 
   AND (table1.code = 3 and table1.type <> 'g2')
   AND (table2.start_data IS NULL OR table2.end_date IS NULL OR table2.program_id IS NULL)
```

I get this is what you are literally asking for but it is not what you think it is

```
AND table1.type NOT IN ('aa', 'cc') 
AND (table1.code = 3 and table1.type <> 'g2')
```

is the same as

```
AND table1.type NOT IN ('aa', 'cc')
AND table1.type <> 'g2' 
AND table1.code = 3
```

is the same as

```
AND table1.type NOT IN ('aa', 'cc', 'g2')
AND table1.code = 3
```

I think what you mean to ask for is something like

```
AND (    table1.type NOT IN ('aa', 'cc') 
      or (table1.code = 3 and table1.type <> 'g2') 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to use the INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT table1.customer_id,type,start_date,end_date,Program_id
  FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
  WHERE table1.type != 'aa' 
    AND  table1.type != 'cc' 
    AND table1.type != 'g2'
    AND table1.code = 3
   AND (table2.start_data IS NULL OR table2.end_date IS NULL OR table2.program_id IS NULL)
```

Let me know if it works fine with you!

Regrads,
ANDOURA

Comment: This looks close. However the table1.code = 3 only applies for type = 'g2'

Comment: Hope it gaves you the solution to your issue :)